# How to calculate area of Irregular polygon drawn on map fragment using Google map API V2 in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, google-maps-api-2

I have captured multiple points by moving around field and saved it in array list of Lat Long. From these points I have drawn polygon on my map fragment. Now I have to calculate area of this drawn polygon.For calculating area I want to use this link
[Calculating Irregular Polygon Area](http://www.mathopenref.com/coordpolygonarea.html)
Now for using this formula I have to convert my Lat Long(which are in degrees) vertices into corresponding meters , so how to do that?

Also is there any other way to solve this problem. I know we can directly use computeArea() method if java script is used but I want solution for this native Google map application.

Comment: @CommonsWare hey thanks I am stalked on this since from more than two weeks I will try this link and let you know. Thanks for this.

Comment: You will find other resources by a simple search for `area polygon latitude longitude`.

Comment: @CommonsWare in the link above for spherical radius what to use is it earth's radius or any other..?. Please tell me which value to use for this.